# how to apply client side and server side validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I have a form with a button that has to perform both client side and server side checks but the problem is I do not know how to go about it because when the button's type is set to "submit"

```
<input type ="submit" name ="submit" value = "submit your form">
```

the jquery code for validation does not work. 
When the button' s type is "button"

```
<input type = "button" name = "send" value = "send">
```

then the server side  checks do not work.
 Please any advice is welcome.

Comment: For client side validation are you using custom or jquery validation plugin?

Comment: @ Mayank Pandey I am not using a plugin I use the button id and I check the fields for emptiness.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your `form` tag

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validate()">
</form>

<script>
    function validate(){
        // do all validations here on form fields
    }
</script>
```

where `validate()` is your javascript function that takes care of validation. if validation is successful, return true from that function else, return false. this will prevent the form from being posted if it's invalid.

for server-side validation, you'll have to catch the form values in your php, and check each value as you want.

Comment: if I understand you correctly for the client side validation I do not use the button's id but a function and on client side I use the if(isset($_POST['submit']))?

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain so much why fail in server side, but I think you need to add return false or preventDefault in your js validation. There are so ways but the validation must be that send the form, not the button itself

Comment: what do you mean by the validation must be that send the form and not the button itself should i use the name of the form instead of the button then? But what happens when i have different forms whose data is to be submitted as a bunch then?